# applying formula in R to multiple rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame lets say

```
a   b
1   10
2   13
```

and I have another data frame where I have 1 value "c" which is equal to 0.3
I want to create column  "d" in the first data frame using the following formula

```
1st row will be 1*10*.3
2nd row will be 2*13*.3
```

please notice .3 is common.

please suggest an R function for this.

Comment: Isn't this just `df1$a * df1$b * 0.3` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply a function to a data frame or matrix by rows, you use `apply`, with the `MARGIN` argument as 1. Here the function you want is `prod`, or since you only have two columns, you could use `*`. The `apply` call takes the products row-wise, giving you a vector of length == `nrow(df)`.  You multiply that vector directly by `0.3`, giving you the values, and assign it to a new column with `df$c<-`

```
df$c <- apply(df, 1, prod)*0.3
df
   a  b    c
1  1  2  0.6
2 10 13 39.0
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 10), b = c(2, 13))
df
   a  b
1  1  2
2 10 13
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and assuming that `df2` will only contain 1 column named `c` with 1 row with value = `0.3`:

```
require(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2), b = c(10, 13))
df2 <- data.frame(c = 0.3)

df1 %>%
  mutate(d = a * b * df2$c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `Reduce` with `*`

```
df$c <- Reduce(`*`, df) * 0.3
df$c
#[1]  0.6 39.0
```

---

Or we can use `rowProds` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
df$c <- 0.3 * rowProds(as.matrix(df))
```